# Using if-statement to compare strings

Tags: android

How can i get my code to compare the string inputted by the user - so lets say the  user presses keypad_1 , i then want to press the keypad_hash button and display incorrect to the user - The issue is when i press keypad_hash nothing happens thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
if ("1".equals(answer.getText()))
```

should be:

```
if ("1".equals(answer.getText().toString()))
```

getText returns a CharSequence, not a string.  From the documentation on String:

> public boolean equals(Object anObject)
>
> Compares this string to the
>   specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is
>   not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of
>   characters as this object.